# How to collapse/expand list using bootstrap/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started working with twitter-bootstrap

In my website, I want to toggle a list containing folder's content like this:
when clicked on `<i class="icon-folder-open">` it should toggle to `<i class="icon-folder-close">` and it should **hide** item 1 and item 2

Here is my initial code which shows folder-open icon and all items in that folder.

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i></a>&nbsp;Item in folder</li>
<ul>item 1</ul>
<ul>item 2</ul>
```

I want to add screenshot for more clarity, but cannot find a way to put it here. Let me know if question is not clear, I will try to explain more.

I know there could be millions of way to do it. I am looking for something small and efficient and within bootstrap/jQuery realm.

Here is screenshot when it is open

http://i47.tinypic.com/2dj5ok6.png

And when it is closed

http://i49.tinypic.com/1dzlna.png

Comment: Bootstrap has a built in accordion function called "Collapse": http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: Something like this: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/?

Comment: Not like that. Let me post a screenshot

Comment: I updated question with screenshot and also going over tutorial pages both of you suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-Edit-

Updated plunk to reflect OP's provided screen-shots -> [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2PUiNqdQKLsBVhyeKLtm?p=preview)

---

OP,

Is http://plnkr.co/edit/2PUiNqdQKLsBVhyeKLtm?p=preview what you're looking to do?

User clicks button -> toggles other element on/off -> toggle the button's icon `icon-folder-open` / `icon-folder-close`.

Comment: +1. Thanks. This is what I needed. Thanks for code example. I will accept this answer after few minutes. btw, will it work for nested lists too?

Comment: Hey I get both folder-open and folder-close icon side by side, when I use your code, see screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/kesupj/6. Don't know why plunk didn't show this.

Comment: It worked after I copied your script.js code into my main.js.

Comment: Is there a way to set it so that it starts off collapsed? preferable but adding a class or attribute?

Comment: Change `<div id="demo" class="collapse in">` to `<div id="demo" class="collapse out">` and `<a id="toggler" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" class="active" data-target="#demo">` to `<a id="toggler" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" class="inactive" data-target="#demo">`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue I have used line-height for p element in li. So li with auto height give me size that I need.